# Cannot connect Solaris 10 to Windows 7

Tags: virtual-machine, solaris

I'm trying to connect a Solaris VM (powered by VMware Player) to Windows Explorer in Windows 7. When I try to map the network drive I get the following:

> The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.

I am using the URL below which has worked on a machine I used before. The only thing that has changed is the IP address of the Solaris machine. I am able to connect to the VM via PuTTY.

```
\\1.2.3.4\xxx\yyy
```

I checked and I think Samba is running:

```
root   375     1   0 09:53:39 ?           0:00 /usr/sfw/sbin/smbd -D
root   376   375   0 09:53:40 ?           0:00 /usr/sfw/sbin/smbd –D
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the firewall within the guest and make sure it is allowing the proper samba/nbd ports inbound.
2. Make sure you're actually running `nmbd` (I believe it's the companion NetBIOS service for Samba, which is required even if you aren't using the raw NetBIOS protocol... nowadays we use NetBIOS over IP, which is what `nmbd` is for.)
3. Make sure the host firewall (security software, built-in Windows firewall, etc) isn't interfering with the guest's attempts to host `smbd` and `nmbd`. If I had a nickle for every time a Windows firewall blocked someone trying to do something interesting with their PC, I could pay for the gulf oil spill cleanup.